# Celery Task not working with redis in flask docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, redis, celery

I am trying to run a celery task in a flask docker container and I am getting error like below when celery task is executed

```
web_1     |     sock.connect(socket_address)
web_1     | OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
web_1     | 
web_1     | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: **[shown below]**

web_1     |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 571, in connect
web_1     |     raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
web_1     | redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.
```

Without the celery task the application is working fine

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=app/main.py
      - FLASK_DEBUG=1
      - 'RUN=flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80'
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:6.2.6
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    expose: 
      - "6379"

  worker:
    build:
      context: ./
    hostname: worker
    command: "cd /app/routes && celery -A celery_tasks.celery worker --loglevel=info"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from instance import config, exts
from decouple import config as con

def create_app(config_class=config.Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config.Config)
    app.secret_key = con('flask_secret_key')
    
    exts.mail.init_app(app)

    from routes.test_route import test_api
    app.register_blueprint(test_api)
    return app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, port=80)
```

I am using  Flask blueprint for splitting the api routes

**test_route.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint
from instance.exts import celery

test_api = Blueprint('test_api', __name__)


@test_api.route('/test/<string:name>')
def testfnn(name):
    task = celery.send_task('CeleryTask.reverse',args=[name])
    return task.id
```

Celery tasks are also written in separate file

**celery_tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from decouple import config
import time

celery= Celery('tasks', 
                broker = config('CELERY_BROKER_URL'), 
                backend = config('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'))

class CeleryTask:
    @celery.task(name='CeleryTask.reverse')
    def reverse(string):
        time.sleep(25)
        return string[::-1]
```

**.env**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.8
RUN apt-get update
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
CMD ["python", "app/main.py"]
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==2.0.3
celery==5.2.3
python-decouple==3.5
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
redis==4.0.2
SQLAlchemy==1.4.32
```

**Folder Structure**

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You problem seems to be related to the redis connection. It's not accessible from localhost:6379. You need to map the port 6379 in the host to the port 6379 in the container (in the docker-compose.yml).

Comment: @python123 I tried with `ports - "6379:6379"` in docker-compose.yml which also gave the same error

Comment: Are you rebuilding the image ? Can you update your question and show me your new docker-compose.yml, please ?

Comment: @python123 updated docker-compose.yml in question

Comment: Ok, I will try to reproduce

Comment: Could you add the Dockerfile ?

Comment: @python123 Attached Dockerfile in the question

Comment: Where is the requirements.txt ? Could you please make sure the issue is reproducible with the info you give ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242887/discussion-between-imhans4305-and-python123).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end of your `docker-compose.yml` you can add:

```
networks:
  your_net_name:
    name: your_net_name
```

And in each container:

```
networks:
      - your_net_name
```

These two steps will put all the containers at the same network. By default docker creates one, but as I've had problems letting them be auto-renamed, I think this approach gives you more control.

Finally I'd also change your `env` variable to use the container address:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis_addr/0
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis_addr/0
```

So you'd also add this section to your redis container:

`hostname: redis_addr`

This way the  `env` var will get whatever address docker has assigned to the container.

Comment: I am bit confused as im new to docker. Is it possible to provide in file form. is it possible to give anything for your_net_name

Comment: Yes, you can replace "your_net_name" for anything you want.

Comment: One example [here](https://github.com/edugmes/docker-env/blob/main/containers/django_cassandra/docker-compose.yml) using same `network`

Comment: You should not need to manually declare any `networks:` at all; the `default` network Compose automatically provides for you should work fine for most applications.  Using the Compose service name as the host name is critical, though.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation says more on this.

Comment: @David Maze By declaring manual networks the problem is solved. Just out of curiosity to know , is there any other way to resolve this error without declaring custom network ?

Comment: `localhost` in Docker usually means the current container, so when you set `CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'` you told Celery to talk to itself and not the Redis container.  Changing that to `redis://redis:6379/0` is enough; you do not need to declare any `networks:`.

Comment: @imhans4305 I'm glad it seems you got it solved by declaring a network. Please don't forget to accept the answer or post your own answer (if the solution was something else). That way you may help other with similar issues :)